# XHR2 file transfers. Accessing binary data during `progress` event handler

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm able to perform chunked XHR requests, fetching a piece of a file specified by the `Range` header. However a file transfer will always likely be faster when downloading the whole file at once with a single XHR request, rather than implementing fetched chunks each with their own XHR request.

What I'm wondering is, if I begin a direct download, is there any way to access the binary data that is being download before the download is complete? There is a `progress` handler, which reports on the total size, and amount currently downloaded. Is there any way to access all or a portion of the already downloaded data?

Basically, as a transfer is in progress, I need to be able to break the file into chunks and perform operations on it. I cannot wait until the download is finished to do this. I also need the download to be as fast as possible, which is why the chunking mechanism is not ideal, it seems it's always going to be slower.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xhr.response` or `xhr.responseText` to get response for the moment. **It works only for text data.**

Example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (){  //could be .onprogress also
    console.log(xhr.response);
});
xhr.open(someMethod, someUrl);
xhr.send();
```

Important note: `.response` contains **full** response, not the portion, that was loaded since previous progress event

For binary data, there is `moz-blob` and `moz-chunked-arraybuffer` responseTypes, but it is not standartized.

Comment: This only works for text though, OP asked about binary data.

Comment: Yeah, I am downloading large (several gigs) of binary data. When I log either `xhr.response` or `e.response` (`e` being the param passed during the `progress` callback handler). I get `null` and `undefined` respectively - until the last callback (when the file transfer is complete) at which point `xhr.response` becomes a `Blob`. Therefore it doesn't work for getting the binary data while the transfer is still in progress.

Comment: @Musa, why do you think that this is only for text? I tested wit pictures

Comment: Your example uses text, regardless of the file type. Set the responseType to blob or arraybuffer to use binary data.

Comment: For me here in Chrome only worked with text responseType. When trying to set blob or arraybuffer the xhr.response is undefined.